# YA SF novel with a remote control for parallel universe jumping

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, parallel-universe

When I was a kid I read a sci-fi novel for children, the full name of which is unfortunately not coming back to me. Here's what (I think) I remember:

- the story features a handheld device that allows one to jump into some kind of parallel universe
- not 100% sure, but I think it was just one parallel universe, with "evil twin" versions of the main characters
- the cover had a picture of the device on it, which may have looked vaguely like a ColecoVision controller
- it's probably from the early '90s
- I think the title is *Strange ________*

Comment: One of these; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=starts_with&TERM_1=Strange&C=AND&USE_2=title_title&O_2=exact&TERM_2=&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: Like one of these; https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1104/2322/products/ColecoVision-Controller-FR_5d23d077-9738-4017-b87e-a8ae1f3961d9.jpg?v=1515610452?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it with your help, Valorum, thank you!

It was [Strange Attractors](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33475) by William Sleator.

[image: cover]

Apparently the device was a modified calculator, and it was used for time travel (which leads to a split timeline and antagonist versions of two of the main characters).

Comment: [Glad to have been of assistance!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)